# Mocking Time - `hidden_include::traits::Time` cannot be made into an object

Tags: frame

I am working on testing my pallet.

in my mock.rs:

```
impl pallet_x::Config for Test {
    type Event = Event;
    type Time = Time<Moment = u64>;
}
```

when running `cargo test` I am getting this error:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `hidden_include::traits::Time` cannot be made into an object --> /src/mock.rs:86:17
    | 86  |   type Time = Time<Moment = u64>;
    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `hidden_include::traits::Time` cannot be made into an object
```

when running `cargo build` there are no issues.

`Time` is imported with:

```
use frame_support::traits::Time;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the compiler is complaining about not being able to make an object out of `Time` is because it is a trait, whereas you need to provide a concrete type which implements the `Time` trait. Currently, the only type that implements the `Time` trait is the [timestamp module](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/timestamp/src/lib.rs#L284-L291). So you should add the timestamp module to your mock runtime and then set `type Time = Timestamp;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot works like charm